# HTML: aligning the text in all the cells of a table?

Tags: html, wordpress

While making a table in html, I can format the text of the whole table by putting some style values inside the "table" tag, and I can format a row by putting style values in the "tr" tag. Some values that work this way are "font-family," "font-size," and "color." However, other values do not work this way, e.g. "text-align." If I want to align the text inside the cells, I have to put the "text-align" value in each "td" tag.

Is there a way to format the text inside all the cells by entering the "text-align" value just one time?

I cannot use CSS, because the hosting website does not allow it (it is a wordpress.com blog).

Comment: Text-align on the row works fine https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0ac0tsu3/

Comment: Also be sure to check that the items inside the table that are not aligning to the center are not being aligned to the left on their class or selector